# How to create an interractive command line interface?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface

I would like to know how to make a user friendly command line interface such as ng cli.

[image]

I have had a look at the ng cli github repo. But it is quite big and do not really know where to start from.

Also, I've heard about `NCURSES`, but it seems quite old and the main mirror gives 404 in the documentation. Isn't there any alternative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like `dialog`?

```
list=(option1 option2 option3)
dialog --no-items --menu "menu example" 0 0 0 "${list[@]}"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, for example ! Is there a list of all the similar functionalities somewhere ?

Comment: Googled [this](https://alternativeto.net/software/dialog/?platform=linux)